# Automatic copying and renaming of a file as soon as it is in the directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm relatively new to programming so I need some help.

I have 2 directories

- C:\test1
- C:\test2

So in test1 will get constantly get files.

Which look like this:

- testA000_00001.txt0..txt
- test00A0_00102.txt1..txt
- test00A0_00102_00123.txt45..txt

...

- testG000_00999.txt999..txt
- testH000_00013.txt0..txt

Since its essential that the files in test1 stay the way that they are I'm gonna need them in test2.

And since test2 needs to be the current version it  is needed to be done the moment the files are in test1.

**But** without the .txt0. - .txt999. part.

- testA000_00001.txt
- test00A0_00102.txt
- test00A0_00102_00123.txt
  ...
- testG000_00999.txt
- testH000_00013.txt

Its also **essential** that these files are only copied once since they aren't gonna stay in test2 for long.

I tried it with xcopy and some other versions of copy but each time it copies the files back into test2 and after I move the files from test2 the files are copied into it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sry cant comment yet)

I dont have exact code (working on it)
What i think would work is to:

- Check a text file for things it alr coppied
- schedual a task to run every minute or so
- move to the folder you want
- Use the dir command to take all files in the current directory
- Copy them
- Write these to a text file
- Change The names
- loop

When i get the code done i will edit.
Also moving them assoon as they enter the directory is very resource intensive but might be possible if the code is very efficient.

```
#make a folder
md "C:\test\test3"
#move to test1
cd "C:\test\test1"

# Presets
$txt = ".txt"
$files = dir
#clean up the files list
$files = $files -split "`r`n"

#for each file it found 
foreach ($line in $files) {
#move the file from test1 to test 3
    Copy-Item "C:\test\test1\$line" -destination "C:\Test\test3"
    #take the first 14 chars from the file name
    $line_name = $line.Substring(0, 14)
    #add a .txt extension
    $line_name = $line_name + $txt
    #rename the files in test3
    Rename-Item -path "C:\test\test3\$line" -NewName "$line_name"
    #move the files to test 2 and if they alr exist replace(update) them
    Move-Item -Path "C:\test\test3\$line_name" -Destination "C:\Test\test2" -Force
    }
    Remove-Item –path "C:\test\test3" –recurse -force
```

This Code is super close to working but i might not be able to finish today.
It only failes to move the file: test00A0_00102_00123.txt45..txt
due to the name not working. I will update the script when it works fully.

Comment: @NoragaPlease flag this as a anwser (The little checkmark under the votes)